# Issue with Powerpoint VBA/VBScript - Presentation opening behind windows explorer/unactivated

Tags: vba, vbscript

I have code to open a presentation from a VBScript file:

```
Set oApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
oApp.visible = true
Set oPres = oApp.Presentations.Open("\\nuth-dept02\Stand Up Meeting Group\Stand Up Wall Presentation Files - Updated\Stand Up Title Page - With Macros.pptm")
oApp.Run "\\nuth-dept02\Stand Up Meeting Group\Stand Up Wall Presentation Files - Updated\Stand Up Title Page - With Macros.pptm!Open_Presentation"
```

This triggers running a macro in the file which opens another PowerPoint presentation.

Everything opens fine, the problem I have is that when running the open of the first presentation from the VBScript file, it opens behind the windows explorer menu and a notification for it oepning flashes on the windows tooldbar. This doesn't happen when running the macro direct from the PowerPoint file.

This causes a problem later on in my code because I have a trigger for slideshows to run. Due to the flashing notification on the toolbar this prevents them from opening automatically and I have to click on them individually/ users have to click individually. It is really annoying.

I have tried adding VBA code into the presentation to maximise the presentations and then minimise to act as if it had been opened. I have tried sendkeys added into the vbscript to minimise other windows. None of it has worked.

Any help would be much apprieciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the `AppActivate` method

Comment: What notification does appear? If it asks to confirm the opening, try **putting the script path to PowerPoint Trusted Locations**.

Comment: I have tried the AppActivate method and it does allow me to unselect the first presentation. So this seems like something in the right direction. However, now the two open slideshow windows are flashing orange and thus the toolbar stays above until I click on each slideshow individually. Does anyone have any idea how I activate a slideshow window specifically?

Comment: So I noticed that if I ran the macro from within the PowerPoint vba editor (selecting the relevant bit and running), it ran exactly as I wanted. However, it also did the same thing as from the .vbs file if I ran the macro from within the "view macros"/"run" option within PowerPoint but not in the editor. I checked this and added a sendkeys line of code in the .vbs open routine and it worked perfectly. Although it is annoying because the editor pops up when running the code. Anyone have any idea why this might happen? Seems really strange to me.

Comment: Why do you need to run it inside the editor? Did you try `.AppActivate()`? Can you update the question?